# use of maps in Java and JSP

Tags: jsp, hashmap, jstl

I find it difficult to access a value in JSP from Hashmap whose key contains special characters like ":". I need it as I have to access jcr:title which comes from the back end call. I can get the value from the map and put it back with different key, but is there a way to access such keys in JSP?

more problems arise when the depth increases as in when we are getting list of map of maps etc.

I also tried using map["key"].. but this fails when we are setting it to a parameter using  tag

Thanks in advance

here is how my code looks like

```
<c:forEach var="test" items=${someList(someMap)}>
    ${test.jcr:title} // not working
<c:forEach>


<c:set var="someValue" value="${someMap["someKey"]}"> //this fails
```

Comment: You'd better use Java Beans instead of Maps. And a JSP's job is to generate markup, so it shouldn't have to modify a Map. That said, if instead of "not working" and "fails", you indicated the real code, with the corresponding Java code populating the map, and the exact error messages you get, maybe we could help.

Answer (score 0):

the `":"` character is not valid inside EL expressions (unless you are using the *inline if* operator `? :`), that's why your first attempt "*doesn't work*".

In the second one you should use single quotes inside the EL expression, i.e.:

```
<c:set var="someValue" value="${someMap['someKey']}">
```